# tinymce .Unable to open the session counter file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce, image-uploading

I have a tinymce editor in my admin page. I have activated image uploader via ajaxfileupload.
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/

but there is a problem! it works perfectly in the local but on the server when I click on the image browser ,it shows me :

> Unable to open the session counter file

[image]

any idea?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

> tiny_mce\plugins\ajaxfilemanager\session\gc_counter.ajax.php

permission to 777!!! it works fine now . but I think this is stupid :P

Answer (score 1):

find this file 
\tiny_AjaxFM\plugins\ajaxfilemanager\inc\class.session.php
and clear or comment content of this function

```
function gc()    {

}
```